# Date fomrat of MySQL PHP to be converted in hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date from which I need to extract just the hours and minutes.
The date is displayed in "2012-11-27 13:36:00" format. So I need just 13:36.
I did something like this

```
var currTime = this.event_start;
alert(currTime);
var jsFormat = new Date(currTime);
alert(jsFormat);
```

currtime gives the correct date whereas jsFormat alerts a undefined.

Comment: You can refer [this](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Convert-String-to-Date.aspx) link which contains all function related to dateconversion in javascript

Comment: I need the hours and minutes, the link you shared is just the date. My tag is for timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do it the easy way :)

```
<script>
var currTime = "2012-11-27 13:36:00";
var t1 = currTime.split(' ');
var t2 = t1[1].split(':');
var h = t2[0];
var m = t2[1];

alert(h+':'+m);
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Could you please explain why you split the space and then the t2, t1 thing.

Comment: Split cuts the string in pieces on the string you provide and turns it into an array. the first split makes t1[0] = 2012-11-27, t1[1] = 13:36:00. So i need the second part and split it on ':' to make t2[0] = 13, t2[1] = 36, t2[2] = 00

Comment: Thanks Hugo! Isn't there any js method to do this, if you know. There is one I know from <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp">w3 schools</a> but dint work in my case.

Comment: Split is a JS method :) But I guess you mean by converting it to an actual date and then using getHour and getMinute. That is what Bart and HemantXp are doing. But it means you have to convert the datetime either in PHP or in javascript. I expect the split to be faster then creating an actual Date object. Another thing I am wondering though: if you say this is what you get from PHP, why not just return the hours/minutes from PHP?

Comment: Yeah that is what I want and works good too but I think this is a workaround for the problem. If there is any change I would need to do it's gonna be difficult then. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ISO8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) dates in PHP:

```
 $date = date("c");
```

JavaScript understands them verbatim (in Firebug console):

```
 >>> a = "2012-11-27T13:36:00+0200";
 >>> d = new Date(a);
 Date {Tue Nov 27 2012 12:36:00 GMT+0100 (CET)}
```

You can then easily get all the parts:

```
 >>> d.getMinutes()
 36
```

(Note: I found that Android 2.2 does not support the ISO8601 date correctly in JavaScript in the default browser)

Comment: You mean I should append 00+0200 to my currdate? Not a good way as far as I understand.

Comment: Thought there was more possible in JavaScript, but it seems like the `Date` object is not as versatile as I thought. Splitting (as ugly as it is) seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Date format conversion to js seems difficult, split is a workaround for the problem. But gives correct result.